# 普通形／じしょ形 (Futsuu Kei / Jisho Kei)

Tags: grammar, conjugations

Are 普通形 and 辞書形 different? If so, how do they differ? I would appreciate an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I would guess that what you refer to as 普通形 is what in English is often translated as "casual" or "standard" conjugation as opposed to 丁寧形{ていねいけい} that is the "polite" form instead. [This link](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/card/038.html) seems to prove me right.

On the other hand, 辞書形｛じしょけい｝ is the so-called dictionary form and it's called this way because it is the form in which the verb is found in dictionaries.

To give a concrete example:

Verb: 買う｛かう｝- to buy

**普通形**: 買う (positive and non past. In this case this is the same as the dictionary form), 買わない (negative-non past), 買った (positive-past), 買わなかった (negative-past).

**丁寧形**: 買います (positive-non past), 買いません (negative-non past), 買いました
 (positive-past), 買いませんでした (negative-past).

**辞書形**: It's just 買う. This is how you find the verb "to buy" in any dictionary. You can see it as a non-conjugated basic form as it could be the infinitive in English (in dictionaries you find "buy", not "bought" for example).

Comment: Is 普通形 the same as "short form"?

Comment: @MXMLLN well I suppose you can call it that way as well. Not sure what’s the best translation in English but I guess it’s clear what we are talking about here.

Comment: "Short form" is the name used in the Genki Japanese books.

Answer (score 2):

辞書形, in fact, is part of 普通形, which consists of four different forms, including the 〜た form (past affirmative), the 〜なかった form (past negative), the ~ない form (nonpast negative) and finally the root form, a.k.a.　辞書形 (nonpast affirmative). For example, what the root form, 辞書形, is for a verb is much like what "be" is for "is", "are", "was", etc. You can find more detailed explanation [here](https://www.coscom.co.jp/japaneseverb/japaneseverb01-jpr.html) and [here](https://iskk.net/teinei-kei-and-futsuu-kei).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand:

- 辞書形 (dictionary form) is your usual 行く, 買う etc,
- 普通形 (plain form) includes all present+past, positive+negative, noun+verb+adjective plain forms; e.g.

  - iku: 行く　行かない　行った　行かなかった
  - genki: 元気だ　元気だった　げんきだった　元気じゃなかった
  - ii: 良い　良くない　良かった　良くなかった
  - hana: 花だ　花だった　花じゃない　花じゃなかった

You use the dictionary form for forms such as:

- 行くこと (make a verb into a noun)
- 行くことができます (I can go)
- 行く前に、～ (before going, ~)

You use the plain form for forms such as:

- 行かないと 言います (~ said not going)
- 元気だったと 思います (I think ~ is healthy)
- 便利だし、忙しくないし、面白い人行くし、安いです (~ is convenient, not busy, interesting people go, and cheap)

Notice how in these examples you can use nouns/adjectives/verbs in their positive/negative and present/past forms.

The dictionary form is just for verbs.
You could say that the plain form for verbs is:

- the dictionary form for the present;
- the ta-form for the past
- the nai-form (without i) for the negative present
- the nai-form (without i) +katta for the past

And similar rules exist for i/na adjectives and nouns.